# Problem in view with moving comments to a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, loops, partial

So originally I had a structure like this in my video view:

```
<% @video.comment_titles.each do |comment_title| %>
    <%= comment_title.title %>
    <% comment_title.comments.each do |comment| %>
        <%= comment.body %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

and this worked fine because when a user added a comment, they picked a comment title that it would be added under, and then all the comments belonging to a title would be added to that title. However, I now want to place the comments into a partial, so I did something like this:

```
<% @video.comment_titles.each do |comment_title| %>
    <%= comment_title.title %>
    <% comment_title.comments.each do |comment| %>
       <%= render @video.comments %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

and i put all of the comment generation into comments/_comment.html.erb

However, this does not add the comments as I intend them to be added. Comments are added under all comment titles even if they only belong to one comment title.

So my question is how can I move the creation of comments to a partial in the comments directory while keeping my visual structure the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're passing *all* of the video's comments - `@video.comments` - to the partial. Change:

```
<%= render @video.comments %>
```

to:

```
<%= render comment %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean:

```
<% @video.comment_titles.each do |comment_title| %>
  <%= comment_title.title %>

  <%= render comment_title.comments %>
<% end %>
```

?